# how can i get highest marks datewise in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, select, sql-order-by

I am trying to get the highest marks datewise in mysql.

When i ran this query :-

```
select tid from post order by marks desc limit 0,10;
```

I get the highest marks but not datewise.

And when i run this query.

```
select tid from post order by date desc limit 0,10.
```

i get value date wise first...
But i want to get the highest marks date wise..

For example my table is :--

```
s.no    marks   date
1       97      15-01-2013
2       104     14-01-2013
3       100     16-01-2013
4       105     16-01-2013
```

So, i want to get

```
s.no    marks   date
4       105     16-01-2013
3       100     16-01-2013
1       97      15-01-2013
2       104     14-01-2013
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT tid, marks, date 
FROM post 
ORDER BY date DESC, marks DESC 
LIMIT 0,10;
```

Check this [**SQL FIDDLE DEMO**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d7bd7/2)

**OUTPUT**

```
| ID | MARKS |                           DATE |
-----------------------------------------------
|  4 |   105 | January, 16 2013 00:00:00+0000 |
|  3 |   100 | January, 16 2013 00:00:00+0000 |
|  1 |    97 | January, 15 2013 00:00:00+0000 |
|  2 |   104 | January, 14 2013 00:00:00+0000 |
```

Comment: @user1982661 Check the demo link.

Comment: @user1982661 What is the datatype of date column in your table?

Comment: current_timestamp is the data type of date column in mysql

Comment: @user1982661 Than this query will work. If not than fiddle demo where it gives wrong anwser?

Comment: Great ! Working now.. Thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 0):

To get the results shown in your question, you merely need sort the table first by date and then by marks:

```
SELECT * FROM post ORDER BY date DESC, marks DESC LIMIT 10
```

However, if you want the maximum marks from each date, you will need to *group* your table on date, selecting the maximum marks from each group:

```
SELECT date, MAX(marks) AS marks FROM post GROUP BY date LIMIT 10
```

If you want to get other data from the maximal record, such as the `tid`, then you must join the result of this query back to your table:

```
SELECT post.* FROM post NATURAL JOIN (
  SELECT date, MAX(marks) AS marks FROM post GROUP BY date LIMIT 10
) t
```

Comment: i am getting the error :-
`every derived table must have its own alias`

Comment: @user1982661: Include that trailing `t`.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT 
        post.date,
        p.Marks
FROM post 
INNER JOIN (
            SELECT 
                MAX(marks) as Marks , 
                date , 
                s.no 
            FROM posts 
            GROUP BY s.no
            )  as p ON p.date = post.date
ORDER BY post.date
```